# Suppressing success beep sounds on enter, but leave error beep sounds in

Tags: windows, delphi, beep

I have a fairly large program, and I need a way to suppress all the Windows beeps you get on pressing enter. I found a function that allows me to suppress all beep sounds, but I need the error sounds to be fired when something goes wrong, so that is not an option. I saw you could suppress the sound for a single textbox by setting the Key to 0, but this is not an option as there are a LOT of keypress events in my program.

Comment: Please can you explain why pressing ENTER results in beeping. Until we know for sure why you encounter these beeps, we can't tell you how to suppress them.

Comment: It does this on the escape button, and on the enter button. It seems like this is a feature built into Windows itself, as I can fully disable it with a Winapi call. Its firing the beep on any textbox that doesn't support multi-line input

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress these beeps that are produced when an edit control has the focus and you press <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> by setting `TForm.KeyPreview` to `True` and then adding the following `OnKeyPress` event handler for your form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key=#13) or (Key=#27) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

If you have some controls for which you wish to accept <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd>, for instance multi-line edit controls, then you could leave `KeyPreview` as `False`, and handle `OnKeyPress` for each single-line edit control:

```
procedure TForm1.EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key=#13) or (Key=#27) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Or you could leave `KeyPreview` as `True` and then have a form-wide `OnKeyPress` handler that discriminated based on the control that has the focus. For example, a rather crude example:

```
function IsSingleLineEdit(Edit: TCustomEdit): Boolean;
var
  Style: DWORD;
begin
  Style := GetWindowLongPtr(Edit.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
  Result := Style and ES_MULTILINE = 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (ActiveControl is TCustomEdit) 
  and IsSingleLineEdit(TCustomEdit(ActiveControl)) then
    if (Key=#13) or (Key=#27) then
      Key := #0;
end;
```

---

However, I would suggest that you do none of these things. I suggest that you leave the behaviour as it currently is. If neither the form, nor the focused control is going to response to these key presses, then beeping is the most appropriate response. The user presses <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> when she wants to cancel the current dialog. If you are not going to respond to that, then the system beeps to indicate that. Likewise, the user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when she wants to accept the current dialog. Again, since your dialog doesn't respond, a beep is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw you could surpress the sound for a single textbox by setting the Key to 0, but this is not an option as there are a LOT of keypress events in my program. Is there any solution to this?

This is actually the correct approach to do this provided that specific EditBox does have proper code to execute certain action upon pressing the Enter key.

If you don't have any specific code to process some action on pressing the Enter key when in certain field then the Ding sound should be heard to tell the user he is doing something wrong.

Same would go if you are limited specific EditBoxes to only numbers. So that every time when the user presses any letter key the Ding sound is played and the user knows that letters are not allowed. Othervise the user might thing that there is something wrong with his keyboard.

You wouldn't want to be a guy who made a software whose usage resulted in lots of keyboards getting busted. Or would you? :-)

So I'm afraid you would have to do lots of code editing for a lot of KeyPress events. I must admit that I kinda feel sorry for you. Been in similar position once.

As for David Heffernan suggestion about filtering the Enter and Escape keys using forms KeyPreview.

**Don't! Realy! DON'T! Why?**

Becouse by doing so you could interfeere with normal functionality of some other components.

For instance using that code with combination of ComboBox prevents you from using Escape key to colapse the expanded combo box.

Comment: `if (ActiveControl is TCustomEdit) and IsSingleLineEdit(TCustomEdit(ActiveControl)) then`  Ask yourself if a combo box is an edit control.